# Use try_cast in ASP.NET when assigning SQL parameter value before executing a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

Let's say I have a parameter in a stored procedure like this:

```
 @level tinyint
```

Then I execute the procedure through an ASP.NET page like:

```
  ...
  Dim CMD As New SqlCommand
  CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level", txtLevel.text)
  ..
```

Now if `txtLevel.text` includes a number greater than 255 or even is empty, then an error will occur. Is there a quick way to test the value like using `try_cast` when assigning value from an ASP.NET page?

I can write a long function to perform tests for the value, but with a large number of variables I'm afraid it will affect performance, I want a fast way.

Comment: "*I can write a long function to perform tests for the value*" - So are there more tests than the two you already mentioned ("*includes a number greater than 255 or even is empty*")?...if so, please provide them, but either way, it's unlikely to be any less verbose doing it in the database layer. The two tests you mentioned are one line of code either way as well.

Comment: 1) Convert it to a number in code. 2) Validate it with your business logic using the validation framework of your choice **before** you call the SP. 3) [Don't use `AddWithValue`](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: why can't you use `int.TryCast(txtLevel.text, out var level)`?

Comment: Even if the value is valid, you are passing a Unicode string parameter which has to be later converted by SQL Server. [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte.tryparse?view=net-7.0#system-byte-tryparse(system-string-system-byte@)) already exists so you don't need to write much code to assign the validated value to the parameter.

Comment: really !! I just post this code as a simple example to focus on the original question, this is not the original code of the problem ! - anyway thanks for the useful comments.